# Optimizing database types to compact database (SQLite)

Tags: sql, database, types, sqlite

I am working on compacting a database (`SQLite`) and I am trying to optimize the size of the data types that I am assigning in the schema. The data I have can be broadly divided into 3 types of numbers. They are:

1. `101010000` - 9 digits
2. `0` or `1`, - Just one or zero
3. `13.4567` - Float type. I would like to just store 13.45 here.

All the numbers will be used for mathematical manipulation within a program. I am using this website as a reference: http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

I would like to know which data type affinity will give me the most compact database. I am currently getting a database size close to 40 GB!

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In SQLite, integer data types can occupy 1,2,4 or 8 bytes, depending on how big is the data value.
Boolean type is stored as integer 0 or 1 and will always occupy 1 byte.
REAL (float) data needs 8 bytes to store. If you are willing to round your data to 2 decimal digits, you may want to multiply your float data by 100 and store it as 4 byte integer value (and save 4 bytes per value).
9 binary digits that you mentioned should need 2 bytes to store.

How can you optimize your data? There are many strategies.
If you have a lot of boolean fields, you might be able to use one byte to store up to 8 bits. This should allow you to improve storage efficiency by factor of 8.
Another good strategy is to normalize your data: split it into more than 1 table. However, this only works if your data schema can permit such split.

Often, if you have too many indexes, they may significantly increase size of database on disk. Right solution is to revise actual SQL queries are used by software using EXPLAIN, find out indexes which are not really needed and drop them.

Finally, don't forget that using VACUUM FULL you will make database occupy as small space on disk as possible, but running it could take a while and requires exclusive database lock.
Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. I have a doubt though - will SQLite automatically use the 1,2,4 and 8 bytes or do we have to specify something like `TINYINT` for 1 byte and `SMALLINT` for 2 bytes and so on...

Comment: If you read sqlite source code, any type that has INT in name is treated the same as just INTEGER. If you don't trust that SQLite will use 1 byte to store boolean (0 or 1), you can simply create test table with 1 million boolean rows and check how big your db will become on disk (don't forget to vacuum after insert)

Comment: What is the need to `VACCUM` after `INSERT` command for the very first data insertion? Will the data be not compactly entered into the database? Also, I use tab delimited text files to enter the data. Will the size of the database be close to the size of the `.dat` files that I use? What additional information makes the database bigger. Just curious. Thanks

Comment: It should not be really necessary. But, you would want to do this if you want to accurately assess data usage. Also, if you have indexes, they may occupy slightly less space after VACUUM compared to the state they were after one big INSERT. Database size should be close to size of original data, maybe slightly more. But, some fields maybe compacted significantly (like saving 8 bits in one byte)